# Css Div alignment with in divs

Tags: css, layout, html

I want to have the text "Skip - I cant decide" Aprear in the black rectangle centered on the bottom. Ive struggled with the Css to get this done right. Can you point out how to fix my css?

[image: Screenshot]

defaultpage

```
 <div id="pictures">
           <div id="MainPics">
        <div id="RightPic">
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="FirstPicMemberNameLabel" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="FirstPicLink" Width="90%" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div id="LeftPic">
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="SecondPicMemberNameLabel" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="White"
                    Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="SecondPicLink" Width="90%" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="skip">
        <a href="default.aspx">SKIP - I Cant Choose.</a></div>
</div>
```

Css

```
    div#pictures
    {
    }
    div#MainPics
    {
        height: 650px;
        width: 60%;
        -moz-border-radius: 35px;
        border-radius: 35px;
        background-color: Black;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #RightPic
    {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 45%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #LeftPic
    {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 45%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    div#skip
    {
        position: relative;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: Don't give ASP.  Go to the page in your browser and go to View Source (right click menu, usually) and then update your post.  (I can't use ASP in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLh6L/)).

Comment: Give HTML and CSS, not ASP. That way users will be able to help you faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution, move the skip div inside the Mainpics div:

```
<div id="pictures">
    <div id="MainPics">
        <div id="RightPic">
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="FirstPicMemberNameLabel" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="FirstPicLink" Width="90%" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div id="LeftPic">
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="SecondPicMemberNameLabel" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="White"
                    Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="SecondPicLink" Width="90%" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div id="skip">
            <a href="default.aspx">SKIP - I Cant Choose.</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to remain at the bottom at all times you will need to set skip to be positioned absolute

```
#pictures { position:relative }
#skip { position:absolute; bottom:5px; /*5px for a bit of spacing*/ }
```

Comment: Thats perfect spot but it disabled the centering code Do i have to set that absolutly too?                                        margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;

Comment: yes. or you could mess with a negative top margin to get it to the spot

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the #MainPics div. Simply move the CSS you have for #Mainpics to the #pictures div. Here's a fiddle to with the "Skip" link at the bottom -----> [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AeBhW/)

Answer (score 0):

```
div#skip
{
    top:-30px;
    position:relative;
    ...
}
```